# What is the mathematical symbol for finite arithmetic (computer) numbers.

Tags: soft-question, notation

I was wondering how we can refer to numbers in a computer simulation: instead of using $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. So that these symbol reflect the fact that we are using finite arithmetic.

Comment: You can use $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for the naturals less than $n$, for example?

Comment: Do you mean a symbol for all of the [floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Floating-point_numbers)? The [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number)? Some third thing? In any case, even if a symbol is in use, it may not be widely known, so you shouldn't use one without a definition.